# Datepicker: +10 дней от заданной даты

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Как сделать setdate скажем +10 дней от заданной даты, а не от текущей?

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date(2014, 7, 1); // NB: нумерация месяцев начинается с нуля, 7 - это август
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
$('selector').datepicker({
    defaultDate: date,
});
```